# Jhipster entity creation is giving error "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: jhipster

I want to create multiple entities, and use 1st entity as a dropdown in 2nd

So created first entity with name:

[image]

Then I gave it relationship with Jhipster Already created entity User:
[image]

Finally:

[image]

[image]

Now that my entity is created, I am generating second entity and wants to use first entity, as well as user entity to use as dropdown in second entity.

Creating second entity:

[image]

Giving relationship with User entity, just like I gave to First Entity:

[image]

Giving relationship with FirstEntity:

[image]

Failure message:

[image]

Comment: let me edit the question

Comment: Please don't use images for code, it's painful to read, slow to load and cannot be indexed. Just use text with code highlighting. Also, using JDL would be helpful.

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error occurs in `pluralize` function due to an undefined argument. Edit `node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js` file, go to line 928 and see which statement calls pluralize with which variable. This should help you to find what's wrong. I'm not sure that it's related but using `Entity` suffix for your entity names is a bad idea because  JHipster uses it also internally, you might want to give meaningful names even for a PoC.

Comment: Line 928 of index.js: 
relationship.otherEntityRelationshipNamePlural = pluralize(relationship.otherEntityRelationshipName);

Its something to do with otherEntityRelationshipName. Should relationship names be unique? As I have used "user" as relationship name for both entities.

Comment: {
  relationshipName: 'firstEntity',
  otherEntityName: 'firstEntity',
  relationshipType: 'many-to-one',
  relationshipValidateRules: undefined,
  otherEntityField: 'id',
  ownerSide: undefined,
  useJPADerivedIdentifier: undefined,
  otherEntityRelationshipName: undefined
}

This I printed on console by addng a line above line 928: console.log(relationship);